CORS Error When Accessing API from Hosted Frontend (but works on localhost)
I'm facing a CORS issue when trying to access my backend API from a hosted frontend, but the same request works when the frontend is running locally.
Here are the details:

Frontend (Local): http://localhost:3000
Frontend (Hosted): http://example.com:3000 (example.com is replaced
by IP address)
Backend: http://example.com:3500 (example.com is replaced by IP
address)

Error:
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.com:3500/api/login' from origin 'http://example.com:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

When I run the frontend locally on http://localhost:3000 and make requests to the backend at http://example.com:3500, everything works fine.
When I deploy the frontend to http://example.com:3000 and try to access the backend at http://example.com:3500, I get the CORS error mentioned above.
Following is the cors configuration.
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://example.com:3000"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
    corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3600L);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
    return source;
}


In your security filter chain, disable the cors configuration. Here is the line of code:
.cors(cors-> cors.disable())

instead of using corsConfigurationSource() use the above code line(this code line should inside in security filter chain).
